# Python add quotes to all elements in list?

Tags: python

I have a several list with in a dictionary. How do I add quotes around every element in each list?

```
native_american={
"A2" : ["Native, Eskimo Volodko, Apache, Mexico, Central America, Guarani, Rio das Cobras, Katuana, Poturujara, Surui, Waiwai, Yanomama, Zoro, Arsario, Cayapa, Kogui, Inupiat, Lauricocha"],
"A2a" : ["Aleut, Eskimo, Apache, Siberian Eskimo, Chukchi, Dogrib, Innuit, Naukan Na-Dene, Chukchis, Athabaskan"],
"A2b" : ["Paleo Eskimo"]}
```

I would like it to look like....

```
"Native", "Eskimo Volodko", "Apache", "Mexico"
```

Comment: Do these lists actually work? Right now it looks like each list contains only one element as the strings in them have a quote at the beginning and at the end but not for each, individual element.

Comment: Do you mean split each element to multiple elements?

Comment: `dict_wiith_quotes = {i:j[0].split(", ") for i,j in native_american.items()}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
native_american = {key: value[0].split(',') for key, value in native_american.items()}
```

What you have at the moment is a list of one long string.   This splits it into a list of many smaller strings

Comment: Could also consider adding a space to the split string, so there's no excess whitespace. native_american = {key: value[0].split(', ') for key, value in native_american.items()}

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like `"Native", "Eskimo Volodko", "Apache"`?

If so: `[item.strip() for item in list.split(',')]`